Load WASM module within Cloudflare Worker
I am having issues loading an Emscripten-generated WASM module with an interface called Lib for a Cloudflare Worker (using Hono and Wrangler). The export definition is within, sparks.d.ts, and it is automatically generated by Emscripten toolchain with this CMake command: target_link_options(sparks PRIVATE --emit-tsd "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_OUTFILE}>/sparks.d.ts")
Here's the full TypeScript definition in the Worker project under src/sparks.d.ts:
// TypeScript bindings for emscripten-generated code.  Automatically generated at compile time.
declare namespace RuntimeExports {
    let HEAPF32: any;
    let HEAPF64: any;
    let HEAP_DATA_VIEW: any;
    let HEAP8: any;
    let HEAPU8: any;
    let HEAP16: any;
    let HEAPU16: any;
    let HEAP32: any;
    let HEAPU32: any;
    let HEAP64: any;
    let HEAPU64: any;
}
interface WasmModule {
  _main(_0: number, _1: number): number;
  ___set_stack_limits(_0: number, _1: number): void;
}

type EmbindString = ArrayBuffer|Uint8Array|Uint8ClampedArray|Int8Array|string;
export interface Lib {
  get description(): string;
  set description(value: EmbindString);
  version: number;
  to_str(): string;
  delete(): void;
}

interface EmbindModule {
  Lib: {
    new(_0: EmbindString, _1: number): Lib;
    get_instance(_0: EmbindString, _1: number): Lib | null;
  };
}

export type MainModule = WasmModule & typeof RuntimeExports & EmbindModule;
export default function MainModuleFactory (options?: unknown): Promise<MainModule>;

I have the src/index.ts setup in the Worker like this, and it compiles and I can access localhost:8787/api/lib but I always get return c.text("No libptr");
import { Hono } from 'hono';
import { cors } from 'hono/cors';

import Module from './sparks';
import Lib from './sparks';

type Bindings ={
    cors: typeof cors;
}

let libptr: Lib = null;

const loadModule = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const activeModule = await Module({
        preRun: [
            libptr = Lib.get_instance("Calling from JS", 1.2)
        ],
    });
    if (activeModule) {
        if (libptr) {
            console.log(`libptr: ${libptr}`);
            console.log(`libptr.to_str(): ${libptr.to_str()}`);
            libptr.description = "Updated from JS";
            libptr.version = 2.2;
            console.log(`libptr.description: ${libptr.description}\nlibptr.version: ${libptr.version}`);
            libptr.delete();
        } else {

            console.error("No lib ptr");
        }
    } else {
        console.error("Failed to create Lib instance");
    }
}

loadModule();

const app = new Hono<{ Bindings: Bindings }>();

app.use('/api/*', cors());

app.use('/api/lib', async c => {
    if (libptr) {
        return c.text(`libptr:\n\t${libptr.to_str()}`);
    } else {
        return c.text("No libptr");
    }
    
});

export default app;


First, I tried to load the module in the /api/lib request function using await loadModule(). Next, I tried adding a preRun in the Module delcaration as the example code above shows.
I've also tried adding to the bottom of the TypeScript definition file this: export default interface Lib;. I also have tried import Module, { Lib } from './sparks'
